# Connection Refused to Rabbitmq container from Spring boot app Container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I'm facing an error to connect from my spring boot app container to Rabbitmq.

I have attached the two docker containers (**Rabbitmq** and **spring boot** app) with bridge network in my docker compose file:

```
    version: '3.3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5673:5673
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - orchestrator-rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=adminsi
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=test
  orchestrator:
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-orchestrator
      args:
        VERSION: ${VERSION}
    environment:
      - spring_rabbitmq_host=rabbitmq
      - spring_rabbitmq_port=5672
      - spring_rabbitmq_username=adminsi
      - spring_rabbitmq_password=test
    container_name: orchestrator
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - orchestrator-rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 7127:7127

networks:
  orchestrator-rabbitmq:
    external:
      name: orchestrator-rabbitmq
```

the connection is refused by Rabbitmq when my Spring boot app attempts to connect to this latter.
Below the log:

> 11:35:22.176 [main] WARN  o.a.c.c.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer - Failed
> to create connection. It will attempt to connect again when publishing
> a message. orchestrator    | java.net.ConnectException: Connection
> refused orchestrator    |       at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) orchestrator    |
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) orchestrator
> |       at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
> orchestrator    |       at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
> orchestrator    |       at
> java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
> orchestrator    |       at
> java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) orchestrator    |
> at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
> orchestrator    |       at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
> orchestrator    |       at
> com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:156)
> orchestrator    |       at
> com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1213)
> orchestrator    |       at
> com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1170)
> orchestrator    |       at
> com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1128)
> orchestrator    |       at
> com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1321)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEndpoint.connect(RabbitMQEndpoint.java:247)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.openConnectionAndChannelPool(RabbitMQProducer.java:108)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.doStart(RabbitMQProducer.java:163)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.internalAddService(AbstractCamelContext.java:1554)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.addService(AbstractCamelContext.java:1475)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:247)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1655)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:60)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:126)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:116)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doStart(Pipeline.java:221)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor.doStart(FilterProcessor.java:138)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:116)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.doStart(ChoiceProcessor.java:185)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1655)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:60)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:126)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:116)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doStart(Pipeline.java:221)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.startChildServices(RouteService.java:396)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:193)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:121)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:306)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:189)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:3300)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2952)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2903)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2587)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:247)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:119)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:151)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
> orchestrator    |       at
> fr.orange.oab.sie.service.orchestrator.OrchestratorApplication.main(OrchestratorApplication.java:31)
> orchestrator    |       at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) orchestrator    |       at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> orchestrator    |       at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> orchestrator    |       at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
> orchestrator    |       at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)

When I execute the below command inside my spring boot app container (orchestrator in my case) I get the following response:

```
nc -vz rabbitmq 5672
```

The response is:

> Connection to rabbitmq (172.19.0.2) 5672 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

So the tcp connection is succeeded between the two containers, but when I curl to rabbitmq inside my **orchestrator container** with the credentials that are defined in the above docker compose file, I get the connection refused:

```
curl -u "adminsi:test" http://localhost:15672
```

But when I change localhost with rabbitmq as a host like below:

```
curl -u "adminsi:test" http://rabbitmq:15672
```

The response is succeeded !

Below my properties config in spring boot app (**orchestrator**):

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitmq
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=adminsi
spring.rabbitmq.password=test
```

I'm using apache camel to publish messages in rabbitmq (below an example of camel route that read from an API and publish the response in rabbitmq topic):

```
from("direct:OrchestratorDtstoreLoadDataRoute")
                .routeId("orchestrator-dtstore-route")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Reading dtstore projects")
                .removeHeaders("*")
                .setHeader("Content-Type", () -> "application/json")
                .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", () -> "GET")
                .setHeader("Authorization", () -> dtstoreToken)
                .setHeader("x-apikey", () -> dtstoreXapiKey)
                .recipientList(simple("cxfrs:{{cmdb.service.out.dtstore.url}}/projects"))
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "dtstore projects : ${body}")
                .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "rabbitmq:q.cmdb.dtstore.projects?routingKey=dtstore&autoDelete=false&exchangeType=topic")
                .end();
```

The Orchestrator Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17.0.2-jdk-slim
ARG VERSION

ENV ORCHESTRATOR_VERSION=$VERSION

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  nano \
  netcat \
  iputils-ping \
  curl \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY target/orchestrator-$ORCHESTRATOR_VERSION.jar .

EXPOSE 7127

ENTRYPOINT java -jar orchestrator-$ORCHESTRATOR_VERSION.jar
```

I run mvn clean package before running the docker-compose file.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If curl worked then it is most likely your application is not receiving or using the env vars you supplied in the compose file. Also, You should not use localhost as you did in the first curl as that means the orchestrator is trying to open a connection with itself which is why you get connection refused there.

Comment: @FelipeEmerim, as you can see I have configured the rabbitmq host in both the docker-compose and in the app properties itself (spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitmq) ,the same host which is rabbitmq, but it doesn't work unfortunately !!

Comment: I tried to reproduce using this [app](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/tree/main/rabbitmq) with your Dockerfile and a docker compose file adapted to this example app. I could not reproduce so it is elsewhere. I encourage you to do the same to spot your problem. NB: I used `networks:
  orchestrator-rabbitmq:
    driver: bridge` in the docker compose file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the journey, I have found the solution, and yes after modifying the spring properties to these below new properties:

```
camel.component.rabbitmq.hostname=localhost
camel.component.rabbitmq.port=5672
camel.component.rabbitmq.username=adminsi
camel.component.rabbitmq.password=test
```

In this manner, we can tell camel which is bounded to rabbitmq about the host, port, username, and password, before just rabbitmq knows these properties, as a result, camel cannot resolve the rabbitmq's host.

Then I changed the docker-compose environment for the orchestrator container:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5673:5673
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - orchestrator-rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=adminsi
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=test
  orchestrator:
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        VERSION: ${VERSION}
    environment:
      - camel_component_rabbitmq_hostname=rabbitmq
      - camel_component_rabbitmq_port=5672
      - camel_component_rabbitmq_username=adminsi
      - camel_component_rabbitmq_password=test
    container_name: orchestrator
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - orchestrator-rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 7127:7127

networks:
  orchestrator-rabbitmq:
    external:
      name: orchestrator-rabbitmq
```

I have modified the rabbitmq's host property (camel_component_rabbitmq_hostname) to rabbitmq for container resolution.

I hope that my solution works for you, enjoy !

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto please check my solution and give me your feedback.